# Listview needs to start with marked setting

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to figure out this code so i can set each of the listview items to marked, as it is now they start in false and i need to click them to mark each of them. But as this is an settings view they should start as marked.

```
private ListView settingListView;
private String[] strListView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    settingListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.settingsListView);
    strListView = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.settings_list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> objAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, strListView);



    settingListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = ((CheckedTextView) view);
            checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());


            if (position == 0) {
                CustomNotificationManager.setSound(checkedTextView.isChecked());
                try {
                    CustomNotificationManager.makeSound(container.getContext());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (position == 1) {
                CustomNotificationManager.setVibration(checkedTextView.isChecked());
                CustomNotificationManager.vibrate(container.getContext());
            }

            if (position == 2) {
                CustomNotificationManager.setPopUp(checkedTextView.isChecked());
                CustomNotificationManager.makePopUp(container.getContext(), R.drawable.default_node);
            }

            if (position == 3) {
                CustomNotificationManager.setNotification(checkedTextView.isChecked());
                CustomNotificationManager.makeNotficiation(container.getContext(), R.drawable.default_node);
            }

            if (position == 4) {

                CustomNotificationManager.setQuietMode(checkedTextView.isChecked());
            }

        }
    });


    settingListView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

How do i set the individual rows to be marked from start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you just call `setChecked` for every element in the list view after inflating the layout? Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < settingsListView.getCount(); i++) {
    CheckedTextView view= ((CheckedTextView) settingsListView.getChildAt(i));
    view.setChecked(true);
}
```

Or did you only want to set specific items as checked?

But usually for settings you should use the existing PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment classes and access the values from SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

For settings view, you can use SharedPreferences, so you can save the state of your listView items and load this from SharedPreferences in OnCreate of your view. You can get more informations [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)